# How to use lambda as lexical scope in C++

Tags: c++, function, lambda, functional-programming, lexical-scope

The codes are like this:

```
int a = 1;
auto f = [a] {return a;};
a = 100;
std::cout << f() << endl;
return 0;
```

I expected to see `100` as the result. However, the `a` is like freezed when captured in `f`. The result is `1`. Is there a way to keep `a` consistent when `a` changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to capture `a` by reference:

```
auto f = [&a] {return a;};
```

Or simply capture the whole environment by reference:

```
auto f = [&] {return a;};
```